# Python: unique values with longest keys

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I have a dictionary somewhat like this:

```
'/a' : [10, 22, 12]
'/a/b' : [10, 22, 12]
'/a/b/c' : [10, 22, 12]
'/a/b/c/d' : [10, 22, 12]
'/e' : [11, 28, 16]
'/e/f' : [11, 28, 16]
'/e/f/h' : [11, 28, 16]
'/e/f/h/i' : [11, 28, 16]
'/j' : [10, 22, 12]
'/j/k' : [10, 22, 12]
'/j/k/l' : [10, 22, 12]
'/j/k/l/m' : [10, 22, 12]
```

What I want is the following:

```
'/a/b/c/d' : [10, 22, 12]
'/e/f/h/i' : [11, 28, 16]
'/j/k/l/m' : [10, 22, 12]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What if `'/a/b/c/d/e'` was also in the dictionary? What would the expected output be then?

Comment: What about `'/e/f/g/h' : [10, 22, 12]`?

Comment: Then I would want '/a/b/c/d/e' : [10, 22, 12] to be first string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
res = []
for k,v in groupby(sorted(d.items(),key=itemgetter(1)),key=itemgetter(1)):
    v = list(v)
    mx = max(v,key=lambda x:len(x[0]))
    res += [x for x in v if len(x[0]) == len(mx[0])]

res.sort()
for k,v in res:
    print(k,v)
('/a/b/c/d', [10, 22, 12])
('/e/f/h/i', [11, 28, 16])
('/j/k/l/m', [10, 22, 12])
```